# how to make powershell repsond to userinput

Tags: powershell

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<detail>
<centre name = "some1">
    <servername>y56g</servername>
    <ip>xxx.xx.xx.xx</ip>
    <uname>hai</uname>
    <pwd>helo</pwd>
    <dbname>some1DB</dbname>
</centre>
<centre name = "some2">
    <servername>p3ng</servername>
    <ip>yyy.yy.yy.yy</ip>
    <uname>hi</uname>
    <pwd>helo</pwd>
    <dbname>some2DB</dbname>
</centre>
<detail>
```

Above shown is an XML file. I can read the data from powershell.The issue is that:

At sometime powershell ask for a user input as a centre name. I need powershell to check for that entered centre name in the xml document and if it find an entry in that name,powershell must display the associated details such as servername, ip, uname and dbname.

Someone please help me on this...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to show what you test so far.

You can try :

```
$a = [xml](get-content C:\temp\centers.xml)
$b = Read-Host "Enter Center"

if (($c=$a.detail.centre | where {$_.name -eq $b}) -ne $null)
{
  Write-Host $c.name
  Write-Host $c.servername
  Write-Host $c.ip
  Write-Host $c.uname
  Write-Host $c.pwd
  Write-Host $c.dbname
}
```